# Validation parameter of spectrum model

Tags: waves, wave-modeling

In Ocean spectrum modelling there are different modelling procedures are available such as Fung Lee model, JONSWAP model, Elfouhaily model, WWIII model and SWAN model. Among those models based on which parameter we can say this model is comparatively better than another one?

Comment: please edit more information into your question,it will help the ones answering this question to give you a better answer.